# Do I need to authenticate with Flickr api

Tags: api, jekyll, liquid, flickr

This is the first time I've tried to interact with the Flickr api. All I want to do is grab a photoset and display it on my blog. I'm using Jekyll and have downloaded a plugin that is meant to exactly this from [here.](https://github.com/tsmango/jekyll_flickr_set_tag)

Unfortunately, I can't get it to work. What I mean is, it is not accessing any photosets.

The setup instructions ask for an api key. So, I created a test app on flickr and got the api key. That is what I am using.

What strikes me as strange though is that the plugin does not seems to ask for any authentication. In the api calls it makes it simply uses an api key.

If I am accessing public photosets then do I still need to authenticate? If so, how?! Do I need to set my test flick app up differently in someway?

I've been googling around but the flickr docs seem to make lots of assumptions that you know what they're talking about!

EDIT: When I try and build my jekyll site I get this error:

```
Liquid Exception: Caught NameError at ':{"id":"721576077277': uninitialized constant Encoding in flickr.md
```

So I'm guessing that there is something wrong with the custom liquid tag?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with jekyll or the plugin you mention - although it looks like you're having issues not particularly related to the flickr api.

> If I am accessing public photosets then do I still need to
>   authenticate?..

As for the [flickr api](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/), you'll notice that many of the api methods don't require authentication. When you don't provide authentication, you'll get public photo/photoset info. If you pass along authentication token, you'll be able to pass optional params on some of the api methods for private info.

> .. Do I need to set my test flick app up differently in
>   someway?

You'll have to provide more details about your setup and some code examples of what you have so far.